# How do I modify the JSON Body in a POST request with mitmproxy?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am working with an app that sends data to a server with a POST request,

```
POST https://www.somedomain.com//sendImage HTTP/2.0
```

looking like this:

```
{
"user": {
    "consent": true,
    "currentNumberIs": 1,
    "images": {
        "data": "BASE64ENCODED IMAGE",
        "docType": "avatar"
    },
    "totalNumberOfImages": 1
}
```

}

I want to replace the data part of this Json, but only if the docType is avatar. Trying to use a python script for that, that I found here and edited:

```
def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
 if "somedomain.com" in flow.request.pretty_url:
    request_data = json.loads(flow.request.get_text())
    if request_data["user"]["images"]["docType"] == "avatar":
        data = json.loads(flow.response.get_text())
        data["user"]["images"]["data"] = "NEWDATA"
        flow.response.text = json.dumps(data)
```

Launched mitmproxy with -s script.py, but according to the web console, the specific request does not trigger the script at all. Which kinda limits the scope to debug.

Would glady appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you see an error in the event log? It might be the case that your script is failing, causing the request to go through unaltered. You might also benefit from using `ctx.log` to log to the event log for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @nneonneo mentioned in the comments, I would first recommend to make extensive use of `mitmproxy.ctx.log()` to make sure that your event hook is triggered properly. Second, if I understand things correctly, you intend to modify the request and not the response? If you want to modify request contents before they are sent to the server, you need to use the request hook and not the response hook:

```py
def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    # this is executed after we have received the request 
    # from the client, but before it is sent to the server.

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    # this is executed after we have sent the request 
    # to the server and received the response at the proxy.
```

Finally, you currently read from `flow.request.text` and then later assign to `flow.response.text`. I don't know your specific use case, but usually that should be `flow.request.text` as well.

Answer (score -2):

You're altering the flow variable in a function, but not using the edited flow. If you return the new flow you can then use it and post it.

```py
def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> http.HTTPFlow:
  if "somedomain.com" in flow.request.pretty_url:
    request_data = json.loads(flow.request.get_text())
    if request_data["user"]["images"]["docType"] == "avatar":
        data = json.loads(flow.response.get_text())
        data["user"]["images"]["data"] = "NEWDATA"
        flow.response.text = json.dumps(data)
  return flow
```

Comment: This is now how the mitmproxy API works, the event hooks do not return any values.